# sort dataframe columns in R

Tags: shiny

Is there a way to sort dataframe columns in R. I tried with  below, but the result is returning as character instead of dataframe

```
> asd <- data.frame(a = c("fsd","sdfsd"))
> asd <- with(asd,  asd[order(a) , ])
> asd
[1] "fsd"   "sdfsd"
```

Can we get in dataframe only?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:5],y=c(5:1))
  
a[order(a$x),]
a[order(a$y),]

> a[order(a$x),]
  x y
1 A 5
2 B 4
3 C 3
4 D 2
5 E 1
> a[order(a$y),]
  x y
5 E 1
4 D 2
3 C 3
2 B 4
1 A 5
```